# No Access-Control-Allow-Origin Error

Tags: javascript, cors

I was trying to build a horoscope app with Vanilla JavaScript. I am using fetch API to get horoscope details with this [API](https://github.com/tapasweni-pathak/Horoscope-API).

I get this error in the console:

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
Origin 'https://pratik-pdw.github.io' is therefore not allowed access.
If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' 
to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

I have deployed the app as a Github Page.

Answer (score 1):

Your browser is blocking it as it usually allows a request in the same origin for security reasons. You need to do some additional  when you want to do a cross-domain request.

Full refrence about CORS 
https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

You can try with the below:

1. Open the chrome browser which allow access to no 'access-control-allow-origin' header request.

   **chrome.exe --user-data-dir="C:/Chrome dev session" --disable-web-security**
2. Try with [XDomain](https://github.com/jpillora/xdomain),

   > > **XDomain** is a pure JavaScript CORS alternative/polyfill. No server configuration required - just add a proxy.html on the domain you wish to communicate with. This library uses XHook to hook all XHR, so XDomain should work in conjunction with any library.